# How would reverse merfolk navigate on land?

Tags: anatomy, humanoid, merfolk, senses, animal-locomotion

A reverse merfolk is a creature with the head and chest of a fish with the legs and lower parts of a human. While they would be able to walk around by their legs, they may have issues with their ability to navigate

As fish do not have necks, and humans walk upright, a reverse mermaid would more-or-less be stuck looking straight up into the sky

Is there any plausible way that these beings could find their way on land?

Comment: Some fish have bulbous eyes that allow them to see near 180º per side and they could see forward when upright. Alternatively, why would RM be perpetually looking skyward and not hunch over to see forward?

Comment: Apart from navigation issues.. being bipedal on land, no arms could negatively affect balance.

Comment: How Kuo-toan! https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Kuo-toa

Comment: @coll - I *beg* you to illustrate your vision of the fish person, with the bulbous eyes, hunching as you describe.  Then post it as an answer.  I know you can do it!

Comment: They might not have necks, but can they bend torso, at least temporarily?

Comment: "How would reverse merfolk navigate on land?" With a globe full of water over their head to keep their gills wet and working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most fishes, out of necessity, have a field of view covering most of the solid angle surrounding their head, because when you are in the water an attack or a prey can be in every direction. The [fish-eye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens) is called like this for this very reason. Only fishes living on the bottom or burrowing have a more directional field of view.

Because of this, your reverse merfolk will have no problems due to the lack of a neck, as long as they have eyes on the side of the head and each eye as a large field of view. They might miss stereoscopic vision, though.